# Which roots of a negative number can be done?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

I'm an Android programmer and am working on a graphing calculator. I have been looking for the limits on which roots can be done. I have a decent understanding of mathematics but can not seem to find these limits. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: What are the limits on which numbers of y get a real value when x<0 and one gets the yth root of x.

Comment: The word *limit* has a specific meaning in [mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)). Are you using the word *limit* to denote *shortcomings*? Are you asking what is the [*domain*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(mathematics)) of the function $\sqrt \ : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: A limit as in the limit on x+1>0 is that x>-1. Yes, the domain of the function where the result is real.

Comment: Ok. Help me out here. As far as I understand $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $x < 0$ and you want to calculate the $y$th root of $x$. That is, compute $$r = x^{\frac{1}{y}}.$$ What is you question then?

Comment: My question is which of these will be real ie. the 3rd root of 8 is real(-2) but the square root of 4 is not real(2i).

Comment: First, please note that the $3$rd root of $-8$ (**not** $8$) is $-2$. The square root of $-4$ (**not** $4$) is $2i$.

Comment: Sorry, missed the negative signs my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x < 0$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$.  Note that $\text{Arg } x = \pi$.

By the definition of the complex logarithm we have $$x^{1/y} = e^{(\log x)/y} = e^{[\log|x| + i(\pi+2\pi\ell)]/y} = e^{(\log |x|)/y} e^{i\pi(1+2\ell)/y}$$ where $\ell$ is any integer.  Thus $x^{1/y}$ has a real value if and only if $(1+2\ell)/y$ is an integer for some $\ell$.  This happens exactly when $y = (1+2m)/n$ for some integers $m$ and $n$ with $n \neq 0$.

Comment: ..which also means that $y$ has to be a rational number.

Comment: @J.D.: Not all rationals will work, like $y= 2$.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I meant $y$ *at least* has to be rational, in the fashion of *necessary but not sufficient* condition.

Comment: @J.d.: Ah, yeah, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Given a real number $x < 0$ and an integer $y \in \mathbb{Z}$. The $y$th root of $x$, given by:
$$ r = x^{\frac{1}{y}} $$
is a real number if and only if $y$ is an odd number.

Comment: How's that work if y is a decimal, as per wikipedia decimal values are neither odd nor even?

Comment: In that case, the answer still applies. If $x$ is a negative real number and $y$ is a real number that is not an integer, then $y$ is not odd, and $x^{\frac1y}$ is not a real number.

Comment: I feel there is something fundamentally wrong with what I said. Write $x = k e^{i \pi}$. Then $$r = x^{\frac{1}{y}} = k^{\frac{1}{y}} e^{i \pi/y + 2\pi n}.$$ For $r \in \mathbb{R}$ we have: $$ \pi/y + 2\pi n \equiv \pi m $$ where both $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Which does not infer the condition on $y$ being odd.

Comment: @J.D.: $x = ke^{i\pi+2\pi n} \Rightarrow r = k^{1/y} e^{i\pi \frac{1+2n}{y}} \Rightarrow y = (1+2n)/k$ where $n$ and $k$ are integers and $k \neq 0$ if you want $r$ to be real.

Comment: In my above comment I didn't mean to use $k$ twice... instead take $y = (1+2n)/m$.